# How to convert Interval type to total hours in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Research is showing me to use Extract(epoch from interval), but I don't think that's an available function in BQ. Any thoughts?

I have an interval like so:
0-0 103 16:10:25

That output would be 0 years (in hours) + 0 months (in hours) + 103 days (in hours) + 16 + 10 min (in hours) + 25 seconds (in hours).

Comment: if you can provide example of input and expected output. - it will help to clarify what exactly you are asking for :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant i made an update. hope it makes sense.

Comment: thanks, it is closer  - so what would be the final output that you expect? actual sum result of those parts expressed in hours?

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: how you plan to deal with years and month being not zeros(0)? or it is expected those always to be zero(0)?

Comment: i have no idea! ideally if there was a 1 for year, then it would be whatever value that is divided by number of hours in a year. where it gets tricky is the month frame.

Comment: without knowing exact year and or month - do you know how many hour in the year? or in the month? interval data type is just interval ...

Answer (score 1):

Consider below example

```
create temp function interval_to_hous(value string) as ((
    select round(sum(cast(part as int64) * weight), 2)
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(value, r'\d+')) part with offset
    join unnest([365*24, 365/12*24, 24, 1, 1/60, 1/3600]) weight with offset
    using (offset)
));
with your_table as (
  select '0-0 103 16:10:25' as col
)
select col, interval_to_hous(col) as hours,
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Obviously, treating hours for year and month parts is approximate :o)

Hope, the rest of code is simple and self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler :)
example :

```
WITH DATA AS (SELECT DATETIME("2023-01-02 10:30:15") - DATETIME("2023-01-01 00:00:00") AS INTERVAL1)

SELECT INTERVAL1, DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME("2023-01-01") + DATA.INTERVAL1, DATETIME("2023-01-01"),SECOND)/3600 AS DIFF_HOURS
FROM DATA
```